# How can I profile/benchmark RAM performance?

Tags: memory, performance, benchmark

I would like to know if my memory hardware is *a* bottleneck of my system performance.

I am dealing with really old hardware (late 2000). If there is room for improvement, I would like to upgrade. This is a sort of pet project for fun to see how much I can get out of a brick-age brick.

Comment: Try memtest86 I think it is. Simple C program you can compile and run to test memory. It might give throughput as a byproduct.